# Objective-C and natural language processing

Tags: c++, objective-c, nlp

I would like do what many have tried/done before me. I want to search through a database of sentences and connect the most similar ones.

User enters: I think Donovan blatantly ripped off Bob Dylan in terms of style.

...search...

Option 1: Donovan's work is unoriginal. 
Option 2: Bob Dylan sounds like he's dying 
Option 3: Pizza juice ripped bag style Bob Dylan

Option 1 and user entry would be matched. I only have experience with C and C++, and I know that Java has some pretty powerful APIs for NLP. Does Obj-C offer anything of the sort? I want to use this is an iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at APIs such as [NSLinguisticTagger](http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/) to identify the parts of speech, identify proper nouns, etc., or [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) to extract semi-structured information. There are also older (but powerful) APIs such as [Latent Semantic Mapping](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=136) to automatically cluster words based on their association (e.g., spam classification). In short, you have some pretty decent options.